# Rails ActiveRecord - association returns redundant rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have my 2 models:

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :channels
  #...

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :machine
  #...
```

In Machine, if I do

```
channels.each do |channel|
```

I see the rows repeated (even many times) in an unintelligible order.

What's up?  Any ideas.  It sure looks like an ActiveRecord bug to me.

I'm on PostgreSQL.  Rails 3.0.3.

Thanks, Oz

Comment: Are you doing a join or include somewhere? Doing `Channel.all.size` has the same output as `Channel.all.uniq.size` ?

Comment: I'm not doing any explicit sql operations.  I'll try the .uniq method.

Comment: But when I look directly at the db table with pgAdmin III, it all looks right - no duplicates

Comment: Channel.all.size = Channel.all.uniq.size

Comment: in the Machine model, if you do `self.channels`, it returns duplicated channels (with the same id but present more than one in the array), is that what's happening?

Comment: Can you run it in the console and show us the output?

Comment: Yes, it shows duplicated channels.  Multiple occurrences of a channel with the same id.  I can't do the console test right now. I have a release this afternoon.  I'll test more and report.